# Splitting string into smaller strings from text input

Tags: c++, string, ifstream

Reading in a text file to a C++ program I'm working on, and storing each string in a node for a double-linked list.  Problem is, I don't know how to split up a line into smaller strings, separating them where the space is.

For instance, one input is

> "Duck Donald 940-666-5678"

and I'm attempting to split it into a `lastname` string, a `firstname` string, and a `phnum` string at the white space.  The result would essentially be:

```
lastname==Duck
firstname==Donald
phnum==940-666-5678
```

How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did (or didn't) it work? And you do know that the input operator `>>` separates input on whitespace?

Comment: No, actually,  That I did not know.  Been working with C++ for three years and I'm still learning things.  Gimme a moment while I test it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I not sure how you're extracting this data, I believe you should just be able to use the `>>` operator.

Example:

```
string lastname;
string firstname;
string phnum;
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open("example.txt");

myFile >> lastname >> firstname >> phnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how you are reading in from your file, but this bit of code may help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
        istringstream iss(s);
        do
        {
            string sub;
            iss >> sub;
            cout << "Substring: " << sub << endl;
        } while (iss);
    }

    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Make sure to search Stackoverflow/Google before asking because you can find your answer really easily many times (see my resources)

Resources: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/, [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)